# How to get number of I/P/B frames of a video file?

Tags: video, opencv, ffmpeg, libavcodec, libavformat

I want to extract information of a video file to get the count of its I/P/B frames. How to do it in ffmpeg? Or should I programming using libavformat and libavcodec to do it? Many thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

On the command line use `ffprobe -show_frames input_file`. you can parse this input to get the frame type information.

You can also do
`ffprobe -show_frames inputfile | grep pict_type`

The string to grep may vary depending on version of ffprobe you have.

Comment: this is amazingly slow; doing the same with ffmpeg is much faster; I'm currently looking for a faster solution as well.